# Error: "The following URL is not Valid" - Unable to publish InfoPath Form

Tags: 2007, infopath

I have little experience with InfoPath Forms. I was been working on SP 2010 to design an InfoPath form using Microsoft InfoPath Designer 2010 and publish it to a site and attach it to a library. Everything went smooth in SP 2010. I have to do the same thing in my SharePoint 2007 machine and hence I designed a new InfoPath form. I opened the Publishing Wizard and tried to publish the form in one of my SharePoint sites. But even when I give a valid URL I'm getting the error "The following URL is not Valid".

Initially it was asking for authentication and never accepted it even when I gave valid username/password and threw the Invalid URL error. So I configured a new machine with Windows Server 2008 R2 x64, SharePoint 2007 x64, Microsoft Office 2007 x86, Visual Studio 2010 x86 and SQL Server 2008 R2 x64.

I tried to design a new form and opened the publishing wizard and gave the URL. This time it accepted the URL and proceeded to the next step. But that is the only time it accepted the URL. After that I'm getting the same error "The following URL is not valid - http://dev01".

I did a google search and I saw the same happened to many others. I'm able to see lot of (crazy) solutions for this issue. The solutions I tried

1. Stopped System Event Notification
   Service and tried publishing
   it(http://serena-yeoh.blogspot.com/2006/08/infopathformurlnotvalid.html)
2. Solutions given here -
   http://www.sharepoint-tips.com/2007/02/publishing-infopath-to-sharepoint.html

But nothing worked. Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I got it resolved. It is because of the ordering of the http handlers. This was in the bottom instead of being at the top

```
<remove verb="*" path="*.asmx" />
```

Reference - http://www.phillduffy.com/blog/post/SharePoint-ASMX-Issue-Resolved.aspx